# Output a value in jQuery from Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

The value of `'content'` is some parsed json. I want to now use this value in my query script. Bellow is what I have so far. The value needs to be in between  `var siteData = { }` **how can I do this?**

What I have so far, but it does not work.

**On my HTML Page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var temp = {{ content }};
</script>
```

**In the builder.js:**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function (event) {

    var siteData = {


       temp;


    }

});
```

this is the error:

```
**var temp = {&quot;name&quot;:&quot;dsaadsa&quot;,&quot;logo&quot;:&quot;**
```

Comment: what is `content`? is it a json string? if so i think you have to mark it as `safe` `{{ content|safe }}` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is escaping the JSON string try {{ content|safe }}

To expand a bit, Django offers all sorts of filters (of which 'safe' is one) that you can apply to variables you are outputting to templates.

Another example would be {{ content|lower }} to output lower case text.

The docs for this are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/)

Answer (score 1):

i think your variable **temp** has value, what you need.

if content equals "*{a:1, b:2}*", html under rendering will be `var temp = {a:1, b:2};`

and then you can write

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function (event) {
    var siteData = temp;     // window.temp
});
```

Comment: no {{ content }} is a django value sorry. I just want to use the value in the script the value of content is some json.

Answer (score 0):

Please post exact errors with full traceback, as they appear in Javascript console, without them is just a shot in the dark..

I believe you have incorrect syntax

`var temp` is global it will be accessible in builder.js, but `siteData` is invalid syntax for object literal; should be something like:

`var siteData = { key: value}`

Comment: error is var temp = {&quot;name&quot;:&quot;dsaadsa&quot;,&quot;logo&quot;:&quot;